# constructing Grails/Groovy where query in run-time

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, where-clause

Is it possible to construct such query in run-time in grails/groovy ?

Let's say I have:

```
def query = Person.where {
     age in 18..65
}
```

and in run-time I wanna add weight to it as :

```
def query = Person.where {
     age in 18..65
     weight in 100..200
}
```

possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [Criteria Queries](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) instead. They allow you to dynamically construct queries like you want very easily. For example, you could create a criteria like this:

```
def result = Person.createCriteria {
    'in'("age", [18..65])

    if (params.includeWeight) {
        'in'("weight", [100..200])
    }
}.list()
```

Answer (score 1):

`Person.where` is a method that takes a `Closure` as argument. A feature that closures have is composition. Here's an example from [Groovy Goodness](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.br/2011/04/groovy-goodness-chain-closures-together.html):

```
def convert = { new Expando(language: it) }

def upper = { it.toUpperCase() }

// Composition.
def upperConvert = convert << upper
```

So you can do something like:

```
def defaultWhere = {
  age in 18..65
}

if(someRuntimeTest) {
  defaultWhere << {
    weight in 100..200
  }
}

Person.where(defaultWhere)
```

Comment: So let's say I read a list of properties from database and place them in a list <String>, can I then insert this into this closure to construct that ? Example : my list hast "weight in 100...200", "height in 100..190", "color=blue" ?

Comment: hmmm if this filters are Strings, you will probably need to eval that.